# How to mock keypress event on Window object with Enzyme / Jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am looking for a way to test my hook for React components:

```
export default function useKeyUp(key: Key, onKeyUp: Function) {
    useEffect(() => {

        const handleUp = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
            const { key: releasedKey } = event
            if (key === releasedKey) {
                if (onKeyUp) {
                    onKeyUp()
                }
            }
        }

        window.addEventListener('keyup', handleUp)

        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleUp)
        }
    }, [key, onKeyUp])
}
```

How can I mock / simulate event fired on the Window object in Jest / Enzyme?

Answer (score 0):

Since `enzyme` can't test react hook directly like [react-hooks-testing-library](https://react-hooks-testing-library.com/). We can use the hook inside a component. Then, use `mount` to render the component.

Use [keyboardEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) constructor to create a "keyup" event and dispatch the event via [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) web API.

E.g.

`useKeyUp.ts`:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

type Key = string;
export default function useKeyUp(key: Key, onKeyUp: Function) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const handleUp = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
      const { key: releasedKey } = event;
      if (key === releasedKey) {
        if (onKeyUp) {
          onKeyUp();
        }
      }
    };

    window.addEventListener('keyup', handleUp);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('keyup', handleUp);
    };
  }, [key, onKeyUp]);
}
```

`useKeyUp.test.tsx`:

```
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import useKeyUp from './useKeyUp';

describe('70938281', () => {
  test('should call onKeyUp callback', () => {
    const mOnKeyUp = jest.fn();
    function TestComp() {
      useKeyUp('s', mOnKeyUp);
      return null;
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<TestComp />);
    const keyUpEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 's' });
    window.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);
    expect(mOnKeyUp).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    wrapper.unmount();
    window.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);
    expect(mOnKeyUp).toBeCalledTimes(1);
  });

  test('should NOT call onKeyUp callback', () => {
    const mOnKeyUp = jest.fn();
    function TestComp() {
      useKeyUp('s', mOnKeyUp);
      return null;
    }
    mount(<TestComp />);
    const keyUpEvent = new KeyboardEvent('keyup', { key: 'a' });
    window.dispatchEvent(keyUpEvent);
    expect(mOnKeyUp).not.toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70938281/useKeyUp.test.tsx (8.484 s)
  70938281
    ✓ should call onKeyUp callback (29 ms)
    ✓ should NOT call onKeyUp callback (2 ms)

-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File         | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files    |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 |                   
 useKeyUp.ts |     100 |       75 |     100 |     100 | 9                 
-------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.937 s
```

`jest.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/js-with-ts',
  testEnvironment: 'enzyme',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['jest-enzyme', 'jest-extended'],
  setupFiles: ['./jest.setup.js'],
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    enzymeAdapter: 'react16',
  },
};
```